# React Native CLI android app showing default welcome page always

Tags: react-native

I am trying to execute an android app created using react native cli.

I have done the following -

```
npm install -g react-native-cli
react-native init AwesomeProject
cd AwesomeProject
react-native run-android
```

On completing all these the app executed in emulator and real device also but always shows the default welcome screen. How to make it show the modified screen.

I tried a lot of tutorial sites but not getting any result.

Comment: This wont help you in giving the complete solution. are you changing the data in app.js or created any other file. if you have created any other file make sure that in index.js you have updated the initial screen.  Also try bundling and run again. to bundle run this in terminal in the project path 
**react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem resolved.

I have done project using create-react-native-app.